# GCC linker error while compiling a static library

Tags: c++, gcc, static-linking

I want to create a static library of all my files so that i could give my mylib.a file to others to execute on their system. I use opencv library in my code. I used the following command to compile my code.

`g++ index.cpp -o display1 -Wl,-Bdynamic pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv -lglut -lGL -lGLU -Wl,-Bstatic mylib.a`

But it is giving the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Try `g++ index.cpp -o display1 mylib.a $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) -lglut -lGL -lGLU`.

Comment: @JakobS.: That article describes **evil hack** to workaround serious misunderstanding of how linking is supposed to work on Linux by author of the mentioned tool. **DON'T DO THAT**.

Comment: @JanHudec: You are right. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the Kerrek SB is right in the comment. The command should be

```
g++ index.cpp -o display1 mylib.a $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) -lglut -lGL -lGLU
```

Explanation:

- The `-Wl,-Bdynamic` and `-Wl,-Bstatic` flags are useless. The linker automatically picks static or dynamic library depending on what it finds. If you give it path to a library (as you do with `mylib.a`) it can't choose and will link the library you provided. If you give it an `-l`*X* flag, it will look for `lib`*X*`.so` or `lib`*X*`.a` and link whichever it finds, but most Linux installations won't have static variants of system libraries, so there is nothing to choose from either.
- It's worse, the `-Wl,-Bdynamic` and `-Wl,-Bstatic` are **wrong**. `-Wl,-Bstatic` *prohibits* linking of shared libraries. That has the side-effect of selecting static libgcc, which implicitly comes last on the linker command line. And you don't seem to have that installed. Most Linux systems don't.
- Each object must be listed on the command-line *before* the libraries it refers to. I would expect `mylib.a` contains functions that need opencv or opengl, so it must be listed before those `-l` flags.